# Upgrade Project Unity 2019 -> 2020

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, upgrade

I had a project made with Unity 2019.3.13f version and I tried to upgrade it into Unity 2021.1 ...

1---

> Script updater for Library\Bee\artifacts\500b0aE.dag\Unity.TerrainTools.Editor.dll failed
> with exitcode -532462766 and stdout: Unhandled exception.
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
> by the target of an invocation.  --->
> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
> path 'A:\UNITY\JuegoRVv1\Unity[^]+(.ref)?.dll$'.    at
> System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
> at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare
> share, FileOptions options)    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
> path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32
> bufferSize, FileOptions options)    at
> System.IO.StreamReader.ValidateArgsAndOpenPath(String path, Encoding
> encoding, Int32 bufferSize)    at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String
> path)    at ScriptUpdater.Program.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__0()
> at ScriptUpdater.Program.Profile[T](Func`1 toProfile, Int64&
> elapsedTime)    at ScriptUpdater.Program.Main(String[] args)    ---
> End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
> arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[]
> parameters)    at Program.Main(String[] args)

2---

> Library\PackageCache\com.unity.terrain-tools@3.0.1-preview\Editor\TerrainTools\NoiseLib\API\NoiseTemplateImporter.cs(10,42):
> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ScriptedImporter' could not
> be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

3---

> Library\PackageCache\com.unity.terrain-tools@3.0.1-preview\Editor\TerrainTools\NoiseLib\API\NoiseTemplateImporter.cs(9,6):
> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ScriptedImporter' could not
> be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried to reimport all and change the path length... Nothing appends.
I'm reading more solutions but i can't find them.

Comment: Did you try to delete the Library folder? Can be savely done since Unity recreates it the next time you open the project ;) Also make sure that package you have installed is up to date and supports the Unity version you are using

Answer (score 0):

Thanks derHugo, I found the solution updating the library terrain-tools 3.0.1 to the experimental one 3.0.2 -- I didn't see it.